# Jquery Mutate Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have come across this plugin but I'm a newbie, I was wondering if anyone could give me an example on how to use this on my website.

http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/

```
<div id="content">
   <h1>Favourite Teams</h1>
   <ul>
     <li>Arsenal</li>
     <li>Man U</li>
     <li>Liverpool</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to check when content div height changes to display more or less teams depending on the available height.

**Updated code**

This is what I managed to come up with. I don't know why it does not work.

```
$('content ul').mutate('height',function (element,info){  
    var h= $(this).height();
    var calculate = h/$(this).find('li').eq(0).height();
    var i = 0;
    $(this).find('li').hide().each(function (){
        if(i<calculate)$(this).show();
        i++;
    })
});
```

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation?

Comment: Example on how to use the plugin: http://www.jqui.net/demo/mutate/ Ones you have implemented something that would meet your requirements, please post the code you have issues with.

Comment: I am new to this and am trying to wrap my head around it. Sorry, I can't see a link for documentation.

Comment: @Lee The link is in your question, it has examples and code samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with you're Selector.
If you want to find the `DIV` with `ID = content` than you should use `$("#content")`

```
$('#content ul').mutate('height',function (element,info){  
    var h= $(this).height();
    var calculate = h/$(this).find('li').eq(0).height();
    var i = 0;
    $(this).find('li').hide().each(function (){
        if(i<calculate)$(this).show();
        i++;
    })
});
```

Comment: sorry just getting the hang of this website. Thanks for the help